# Inconsistent glob.glob results

Tags: python, file-io, filesystems, glob

Can anyone tell me why this command works:

```
lefs = glob.glob(".\lef\*.lef")
```

but this doesnt?

```
techFiles = glob.glob(".\techfile\*.tcl")
```

I have to add the extra backslash in order for it to work:

```
techFiles = glob.glob(".\\techfile\*.tcl")
```

The other line works fine with no extra backslash..
These are just simple files with different extensions.

All files exists and are in the correct directory.

Comment: `\t` is the tab character so glob has nothing to scan.

Comment: Use `r''` if you don't want backslashes to have any special meaning.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it.

Answer (score 0):

in `techFiles = glob.glob(".\techfile\*.tcl")`, `\t` is interpreted as a tabulation char (other "problematic chars are `\b`, `\v`, `\a`, `\x`, `\b`, `\f`, `\U`, `\` followed by a digit, ... I may forget some)

So the path is invalid and `glob.glob` returns nothing.

Your other path contains `\l` and `\*` which doesn't correspond to any escape sequence, so it is not interpreted and kind of works.

To pass string literals as Windows paths, always use raw prefix, it's simpler than escaping each backslash:

```
techFiles = glob.glob(r".\techfile\*.tcl")
```

Slightly off-topic: there's a lot of code examples here with capitalized directory names: ex `glob.glob(".\Techfile\Backlog\*.tcl")`, and I always wondered if it was mere luck, or if most people still don't get this `\t` issue and find a workaround by capitalizing, since Windows paths are case-insensitive...

Comment: Just FYI, Windows is perfectly happy to use forward slashes to separate path segments, and if you do that all your worries go away.

Comment: @kindall true for `glob`, but for some DOS commands (when performing system calls) "/" is seen an option so you have to use backslash. And the interest of pasting a literal path is to avoid to escape or convert to slashes.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I never would have thought of that!